# Force Chrome to send all certificates in chain during TLS

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, ocsp

I have written a TLS code which is doing mutual authentication at Java, so client is sending its certificate after server sends its certificate. I would like to validate all the certificates in certificate chain by OCSP which is coming from client side to server side.

I have written my loop logic as assuming that last certificate is root(CA) certificate in the chain and not to send any OCSP query for it;

```
        int certificateChainSize= x509Certificates.length;

        // Verifies certificate chain respectively (issuer certificate required).
        CertificateResult response = null;

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < certificateChainSize-1 ; i++) {
                response = client.verify(x509Certificates[i], x509Certificates[i+1]);
            }
        } catch (OcspException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I test TLS and get Wireshark capture, I realized that Google Chrome as client has been sending certificate chain without root. As a result; intermediate certificate is not queried because of loop logic, because my code assumed the intermedite certificate is root.

How can I force client to send all nodes of the certificate chain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I realized that Google Chrome as client has been sending certificate chain without root.

That is perfectly normal and the only correct behavior.

The root certificate is the trust anchor which has to be local to the party validating the certificate. Even if it is send it should be ignored when validating the certificate, i.e. only a local trust anchor should be used - otherwise a man in the middle could just provide his own certificate chain including his own root certificte. This means that in this case the server must have the root certificate already locally and thus there is no need for the client to send it.

In other words: don't try to change how Chrome behaves but instead adjust your expectations (and your code) on what the correct behavior is.

Comment: So, how can I send OCSP query for intermediate cert? AFAIK OCSP request contains hashed issuer name and key, but we don't have key of root as issuer, because the root is not exists.

Comment: @korayguney: this is a different question from your original one (which asked how to make Chrome send the root). The main point is that you should not  simply use the certificates as send by the peer in the first place but instead use the trust chain as computed locally as base to verify the validity of the certificates, since it might for example be that the server sends unrelated certificates or that different trust chains are possible (for example due to cross-signing). While I know how to get this computed chain  in OpenSSL I don't know how to access it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Steffen but to give some more facts, here is what [TLS 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2) explicitly says:

> certificate_list:  A sequence (chain) of CertificateEntry structures,
> each containing a single certificate and set of extensions.

and

> The sender's certificate MUST come in the first
> CertificateEntry in the list.  Each following certificate SHOULD
> directly certify the one immediately preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed
> independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
> omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
> possess any omitted certificates.

and finally about ordering:

> Note: Prior to TLS 1.3, "certificate_list" ordering required each
> certificate to certify the one immediately preceding it; however,
> some implementations allowed some flexibility.  Servers sometimes
> send both a current and deprecated intermediate for transitional
> purposes, and others are simply configured incorrectly, but these
> cases can nonetheless be validated properly.  For maximum
> compatibility, all implementations SHOULD be prepared to handle
> potentially extraneous certificates and arbitrary orderings from any
> TLS version, with the exception of the end-entity certificate which
> MUST be first.

So Chrome is correctly applying this specification. You need to change your end to cope with it.